# Does something like this work in asynchronous code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, node.js, callback

```
regular = 'a string';
enriched = enrichString(regular);
sys.puts(enriched);

function enrichString(str){
    //run str through some regex stuff or other string manipulations
    return str;
}
```

Right now it seems to be doing what I hoped it would do but I don't know if its safe. Could this result in undefined sometimes? Do I need to do something like:

```
regular = 'a string';
enriched = enrichString(regular, function(data){sys.puts(data);});

function enrichString(str, cb){
    //run str through some regex stuff or other string manipulations
    cb(str);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need callbacks if your making asychronous non-blocking calls.

```
var string = "foo",
    new_string = enrich(foo);

doStuff(new_string);
```

Is safe if `enrich` is blocking. For example

```
function enrich(str) {
    // do regex stuff with str

    // manipulate it

    return str;
}
```

is blocking so it's safe to do this. Where as

```
function enrich(str) {
    // get some data from the database.

    // store the string in a file.

    return str;
}
```

Uses non blocking IO and is not safe. What you want to do is this :

```
function enrich(str, cb) {
    // get some data from the database.

    // store the string in a file.

    return cb(str);
}

var string = "foo",
    new_string = enrich(foo, function (str) {
        doStuff(new_string);
    });
```

Notice that

`enriched = enrichString(regular, sys.puts(data));`

Does not work because your passing in the return value of `sys.puts(data)` as your function parameter (data is undefined aswell!)

You need to pass in a function.

Comment: @Pointy you still beat me, by doing the old incremental change of answer.

Comment: ah yea messed up that example passing in the sys.puts() - thanks for all the great info

Answer (score 3):

No, you should be fine. Straight runs of computational code are inherently not asynchronous. Callbacks are needed when there's some action involving external resources — file I/O, network operations, some operating system interactions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on Pointy's response, people sometimes force asynchronous behavior with process.nextTick (or in the browser setTimeout(fn,0)) - this forces the current execution context to yield. Ex: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L408-410

Comment: or `setTimeout`, `setInterval` etc.